# mysql-xdevapi getCollections promise return value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, mysql-x-devapi

I've been trying to output the array of collections in my database schema.
Assuming my session works, I'd get an Promise{} output below which I think is normal.

```
        .then(()=>{
            return sess.getSchema('mySchema').getCollection('myCollection')
            .find().fields(['name','age'])
            .execute(row=>{
                console.log(row)
            })
        })
        .then(()=>{
            let r = sess.getSchema('mySchema').getCollections()
            console.log(r)
            return r
        })
```

but if I tried to get the values in the promise

```
            let r = sess.getSchema('mySchema').getCollections()
            r.then(v=>{
                console.log(v)
            })
```

It returns me these session callback functions

```
 [
  {
    getSession: [Function: getSession],
    add: [Function: add],
    addOrReplaceOne: [Function: addOrReplaceOne],
    count: [Function: count],
    existsInDatabase: [Function: existsInDatabase],
    find: [Function: find],
    getName: [Function: getName],
    getSchema: [Function: getSchema],
    inspect: [Function: inspect],
    modify: [Function: modify],
    remove: [Function: remove],
    removeOne: [Function: removeOne],
    replaceOne: [Function: replaceOne],
    dropIndex: [Function: dropIndex],
    createIndex: [Function: createIndex],
    getOne: [Function: getOne]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the way the API works. The [`getCollections()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-Schema.html#getCollections) method returns an array of `Collection` instances. Each instance has that specific set of methods.

So, for instance, if you want to get the collection names, you can do:

```
sess.getSchema('mySchema').getCollections()
  .then(collections => {
    console.log(collections.map(c => c.getName()))
  })
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: This should work , Thanks Friend!  I did not think of that , I was just using it yesterday.

Comment: @ruiquelhas, I'm new to xdevapi, can you help take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62853011/mysql-xdevapi-how-to-return-a-successful-status

Comment: @Jeb50 I've wrote some thoughts there.